# How Can I make maintanance mode in netlify app in react

Tags: reactjs, build, netlify

Error message : ***A "_redirects" file is present in the repository but is missing in the publish directory "build".***

Since it is an **React application**

here I have attached the deployed config image

**[Deployed logs...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVxYU.png)**

added redirect file in git.
directory/_redirects

```
/* /index.html 200
```

directory/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Site Maintenance | Shifter</title>
<style>
  body { text-align: center; padding: 150px; }
  h1 { font-size: 50px; }
  body { font: 20px Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #333; }
  article { display: block; text-align: left; width: 650px; margin: 0 auto; }
  a { color: #dc8100; text-decoration: none; }
  a:hover { color: #333; text-decoration: none; }
</style>

<article>
    <h1>We&rsquo;ll be back soon!</h1>
    <div>
        <p>Sorry for the inconvenience but we&rsquo;re performing some maintenance at the moment. If you need to you can always <a href="https://en.digitalcube.jp/">contact us</a>, otherwise we&rsquo;ll be back online shortly!</p>
        <p>&mdash; The Team</p>
    </div>
</article>
```